# Spring autowiring by parameter name does not work for FtpMessageHandlerSpec

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am unable to autowire org.springframework.integration.ftp.dsl.FtpMessageHandlerSpec by using bean name + parameter name that is same as bean name. I believe that Spring should be able to resolve dependencies when there are multiple beans of same type in case that bean name and target parameter name are the same.

I have config like this:

```
@Configuration
class cfg {

    @Bean
    Object ftpMessageHandlerSpecUser(
            FtpMessageHandlerSpec ftpMessageHandlerSpecA,
            FtpMessageHandlerSpec ftpMessageHandlerSpecB
    ) {
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    FtpMessageHandlerSpec ftpMessageHandlerSpecA() {
        return outboundAdapter(() -> null);
    }

    @Bean
    FtpMessageHandlerSpec ftpMessageHandlerSpecB() {
        return outboundAdapter(() -> null);
    }


}
```

When I try to run it a get following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method ftpMessageHandlerSpecUser in com.example.demo.cfg required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - &ftpMessageHandlerSpecA: defined by method 'ftpMessageHandlerSpecA' in class path resource [com/example/demo/cfg.class]
    - &ftpMessageHandlerSpecB: defined by method 'ftpMessageHandlerSpecB' in class path resource [com/example/demo/cfg.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

When i add @Qualifier to method parameters it works:

```
@Configuration
class cfg {

    @Bean
    Object ftpMessageHandlerSpecUser(
            @Qualifier("ftpMessageHandlerSpecA") FtpMessageHandlerSpec ftpMessageHandlerSpecA,
            @Qualifier("ftpMessageHandlerSpecB") FtpMessageHandlerSpec ftpMessageHandlerSpecB
    ) {
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    FtpMessageHandlerSpec ftpMessageHandlerSpecA() {
        return outboundAdapter(() -> null);
    }

    @Bean
    FtpMessageHandlerSpec ftpMessageHandlerSpecB() {
        return outboundAdapter(() -> null);
    }

}
```

This works:

```
@Configuration
class cfg2 {

    @Bean
    Object foo(
            String beanA,
            String beanB
    ) {
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    String beanA() {
        return "beanA";
    }

    @Bean
    String beanB() {
        return "beanB";
    }

}
```

Why it does not work with FtpMessageHandlerSpec from spring integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSL `*Spec`s are `FactoryBean`s for the underlying SI components; hence the leading `&` on the bean name, so you need a `@Qualifier`.

Exactly what are you trying to achieve by injecting these anyway? They are simply building blocks for integration flows.

Comment: As Gary said: `Spec`s are `FactoryBean`s. You should not to inject exactly them, but rather a target object of those factories. So, in your case try this: `FtpMessageHandler ftpMessageHandlerSpecA` instead. You definitely don't need to call that `get()` by yourself. Unfortunately it's not so easy to hide that method from end-users...

Comment: Thank u. I am injecting these in order to be able to replace them in different environment with different FTP server settings.

Comment: "Replacing" ? That's something wrong. In general they should not be mutated at runtime because they can be shared between different components. So, modifying in one place will definitely effect another one.

Comment: If you talk about different runtime environment, you should think about using `@Profile`. So, one set of beans are going to be available in one env, and another in some other place. You can used different `@Configuration` classes and even have the same bean names over there. The `@Profile` will do the trick to distinguish and avoid conflicts: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-definition-profiles

Comment: I just realized that my answer to why I am injecting it, should have been that i dont need to, i just dont like how big the method defining the flow is. What i want to replace in different environments is session factory (yes, using @Profile). I am not calling get() method since i am injecting it into another java dsl style flow definition.

Comment: Well, all you need is a `SessionFactory` insjection. You definitely don't need to modify those specs: they simply would rely on what ever `SessionFactory` you provide for them!